# If $|\frac{df}{dx}|\le1$ for all points, prove $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|$ at all x and y

Tags: limits

I came across this problem in an exercise on the Mean Value Theorem and L'Hopital's rule, and am not really sure how to prove it. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
As a start, the only thing I could think to do was this:
$$|\frac{df}{dx}|\le1$$
$$-1\le\frac{df}{dx}\le1$$
$$-x\le f(x)\le x$$

However, I am not sure how relevant this is, or if it is correct.

SECOND EDIT:
Upon further inspection I have gotten further, I believe.
By the Mean Value Theorem, there is some point c such that
$$-1\le f'(c)\le 1$$
Which is equivalent to saying
$$-1\le\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\le 1$$
Multiplying by $b-a$ gives
$$-(b-a)\le f(b)-f(a)\le b-a$$
Which I believe is equivalent to
$$|f(b)-f(a)|\le b-a$$
This looks very similar to the form that the answer is in, so am I on the right track or have I gone on a wild goose chase?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: It is a direct application of the angry value theorem.

Comment: You've stated the mean value theorem incorrectly. You should say: for any $a,b$ there exists a $c$ in between $a$ and $b$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. You can substitute this into $|f'(c)|<1$, then clear denominators.

Comment: @runway44 Thanks for the feedback, does that mean it should be something like this? $$|f'(c)|\le 1$$
$$|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}|\le 1$$
$$|f(b)-f(a)|\le |b-a|$$

Comment: Yes youve done it just put mod brackets around $b-a$